# scipy.signal.find_peaks return empty properties

Tags: python, debugging, scipy, peak-detection

I tried to obtain `properties` from [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), but it returns an empty dictionary `{}`. Can anyone help to fix it?

```
line={'x':[3405.024, 3405.312, 3406.176, 3406.464, 3406.752, 3407.04, 3407.328, 3408.192, 3408.48, 3408.768, 3409.056, 3409.344, 3410.208, 3410.496, 3410.784, 3411.072, 3411.36, 3412.224, 3412.512, 3412.8, 3413.088, 3413.376, 3414.24, 3414.528, 3414.816, 3415.104, 3415.392, 3416.256, 3416.544, 3416.832, 3417.12, 3417.408, 3418.272, 3418.56, 3418.848, 3419.136, 3419.424, 3420.288, 3420.576, 3420.864, 3421.152, 3421.44, 3422.304, 3422.592, 3422.88, 3423.168, 3423.456, 3424.32, 3424.608, 3424.896, 3425.184, 3425.472, 3426.336, 3426.624, 3426.912, 3427.2, 3427.488, 3428.352, 3428.64, 3428.928, 3429.216, 3429.504, 3430.368, 3430.656, 3430.944, 3431.232, 3431.52, 3432.384, 3432.672, 3432.96, 3433.248, 3433.536, 3434.4, 3434.688, 3434.976, 3435.264, 3435.552, 3436.416, 3436.704, 3436.992, 3437.28, 3437.568, 3438.432, 3438.72, 3439.008, 3439.296, 3439.584, 3440.448, 3440.736, 3441.024, 3441.312, 3441.6, 3442.464, 3442.752, 3443.04, 3443.328, 3443.616, 3446.784, 3447.072, 3447.36, 3447.648, 3448.512, 3448.8, 3449.088, 3449.376, 3449.664, 3450.528, 3450.816, 3451.104, 3451.392, 3451.68, 3452.544, 3452.832, 3453.12, 3453.408, 3453.696, 3454.56, 3454.848, 3455.136, 3455.424, 3455.712, 3456.576, 3456.864, 3457.152, 3457.44, 3457.728, 3458.592, 3458.88, 3459.168, 3459.456, 3459.744, 3460.608, 3460.896, 3461.184, 3461.472, 3461.76, 3462.624, 3462.912, 3463.2, 3463.488, 3463.776, 3464.64, 3464.928, 3465.216, 3465.504, 3465.792, 3466.656, 3466.944, 3467.232, 3467.52, 3467.808, 3468.672, 3468.96, 3469.248, 3469.536, 3469.824, 3470.688, 3470.976, 3471.552, 3471.84, 3472.704, 3472.992, 3473.28, 3473.568, 3473.856, 3474.72, 3475.008, 3475.296, 3475.584, 3475.872, 3476.736, 3477.024, 3477.312, 3477.6, 3477.888, 3478.752, 3479.04, 3479.328, 3482.784, 3483.072, 3483.36, 3483.648, 3483.936, 3484.8, 3485.088, 3485.376, 3485.664, 3485.952, 3486.816, 3487.104, 3487.392, 3487.68, 3487.968, 3488.832, 3489.12, 3489.408, 3489.696, 3489.984, 3490.848, 3491.136],'y':[2.8704988033738155, 2.855552848626523, 2.8394408991556035, 2.8760938091928283, 2.839230155752019, 2.842457658803069, 2.8410261433228166, 2.8573861450756612, 2.857387021980881, 2.806297422602761, 2.7971283818671346, 2.7816507103799193, 2.731688047826982, 2.7418725745971857, 2.727028143376022, 2.776373497840072, 2.801856492953382, 2.7920703904952764, 2.8003712817530464, 2.7848618280702757, 2.7786797981369897, 2.7352797514124574, 2.741999007214465, 2.7920810188363783, 2.801841637046689, 2.832213052750878, 2.8819813363787383, 2.9318568069410413, 2.981497613758153, 3.0011931879816136, 2.9941795591480016, 2.9941645557792027, 2.9478162494706575, 2.9775519414015075, 2.982208419457967, 2.956031947959084, 2.9583227973910504, 2.964161293518658, 2.9712130327007737, 2.9498071809929405, 2.947371456134651, 2.9521622178702605, 2.9371266647017547, 2.93215460629238, 2.9514305014085975, 2.949006587519915, 2.9596092363229705, 2.934544963099511, 2.9259999819162847, 2.9197764455993918, 2.9089066976394196, 2.9100614536904934, 2.9161729891245227, 2.911935999891451, 2.896417726428179, 2.898940273843373, 2.8951579879203897, 2.886189355260204, 2.9091151063692093, 2.8992706703011177, 2.895453863515079, 2.8788995783497784, 2.8789845854022316, 2.89047933320601, 2.8979224192980593, 2.8881360937889298, 2.896751710195652, 2.8790824784924367, 2.8969734235605875, 2.898082683905878, 2.909342251831121, 2.9070673254146855, 2.8872077101208267, 2.891123474503871, 2.888572314334519, 2.8817986291265023, 2.8753337226251725, 2.8737598581078565, 2.8783575789921154, 2.867808253209416, 2.8497945212357005, 2.8392950365274237, 2.8153576260700426, 2.8185456929134998, 2.8253019924080207, 2.8288712405608827, 2.8221710322062323, 2.8100183794152946, 2.7681498575125953, 2.742390211943808, 2.792849100488907, 2.790026871755891, 2.792735260255324, 2.7746751189360492, 2.7928607427598386, 2.778956818305892, 2.774587510597919, 2.7629222212014386, 2.7385934473474234, 2.745969768703785, 2.7503317074577964, 2.7649130418783114, 2.767732897488769, 2.772028865305056, 2.7619817721377706, 2.7706064899620073, 2.7763126454998215, 2.786212313698737, 2.802673026727067, 2.78340104867985, 2.758183878749916, 2.743656235653572, 2.7701133956928436, 2.760025238913161, 2.7642904134655, 2.7599647903480373, 2.768544885546413, 2.7913152045520464, 2.7854886131704686, 2.7812735815987657, 2.7320161850757247, 2.7231157434265394, 2.6751482107427886, 2.681411567472767, 2.637660451225097, 2.6278522128296027, 2.596465035825378, 2.6169615566163595, 2.5683539101775836, 2.5225643565877998, 2.5427818533230595, 2.5698387209196802, 2.5203688447388806, 2.5314195096680696, 2.5623730621802134, 2.5853420641486036, 2.540136269265092, 2.565455618183025, 2.575464093057478, 2.578758890008093, 2.6105825154513993, 2.5903245474265875, 2.5696223783321663, 2.557233685735461, 2.5978400470167387, 2.611454530182371, 2.606400722406021, 2.6182183639355108, 2.606302545314764, 2.6113411921707956, 2.614691105551711, 2.6279869932301434, 2.619688293530369, 2.6263497361070973, 2.5762707320437723, 2.5516833894135105, 2.5372918619107634, 2.5171641021619755, 2.4983723964184352, 2.5153086713506463, 2.5448086235658294, 2.539356448084917, 2.5895495696020316, 2.6015979885697456, 2.5793537898839447, 2.596757942183393, 2.634237347235472, 2.62573269109998, 2.648973280370734, 2.653850410062133, 2.667541954741026, 2.65954303961076, 2.673108862263467, 2.6476972988331102, 2.6453257760740194, 2.667986307466183, 2.6675609678227357, 2.66105845423031, 2.647232437711875, 2.649478337561501, 2.6590103208820617, 2.6683168473509338, 2.6639166879519123, 2.6527879524755393, 2.6491881433080122, 2.6554116420393234, 2.659090848486373, 2.6190258290305173, 2.6189826877638294, 2.6471901347633344, 2.646685092454985, 2.6367726108298832, 2.6446671748512705, 2.6461789397586024, 2.6534272148910043, 2.640544131372565, 2.6259370611098025, 2.6192824324516666, 2.577783385627213, 2.581229718064362]}

from scipy.signal import find_peaks

max_index, properties = find_peaks(line['y'],prominence=None)
max_x = [line['x'][i] for i in max_index]
max_y = [line['y'][i] for i in max_index]
peak = {'x':max_x,'y':max_y}

print(properties)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `None` to `prominence`. None is already the default value, and is used to signal that no value for the argument was given.

Pass a numeric value as below:

```
max_index, properties = find_peaks(line['y'], prominence=0.1)
max_x = [line['x'][i] for i in max_index]
max_y = [line['y'][i] for i in max_index]
peak = {'x': max_x, 'y': max_y}

print(properties)
```

**Output**

```
{'prominences': array([0.27416504, 0.10761815]), 'left_bases': array([ 14, 132]), 'right_bases': array([158, 158])}
```

Comment: I would also add that the statistics of peak width, being the same as running `scipy.signal.peak_widths`, is obtained by using the keyword `width`. That keyword will serve as a minimum threshold for the detection of peaks.